# Is there a way to grab a copy cookies from a site as it is accessed?

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

I am familiar with Selenium, Requests, and I have read a little about Mechanize.

But I cannot seem to find a way to store the cookies as a site is accessed manually into a cookie jar, to then be applied.

I have tried:

```
    >>> url = 'http://fake.net/login/complex/cookies'
    >>> r = requests.get(url)

    >>> print r.cookies
       {'complex': 'cookies'}
```

But I do not get what I am looking for at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I collect the cookies with selenium:

```
Cookies = driver.get_cookies()
```

And, this is how I load them when needed:

```
for cookie in Cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my silly question. Got lost in the weeds, couldn't see out.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help.